# Paypal: Make product options show after redirecting to Paypal, not on my site

Tags: html, wordpress, paypal

This is my first time working with PayPal, so I appreciate your help and patience.

I am working with a WordPress site. I would like to customize a button with two different options. However, I don't want the dropdown options or PayPal "Buy Now" button to show on my website. I am wrapping the form in my own image (where I outline the two different options), so that takes care of hiding/customizing the submit button. Where I run into issues is with the dropdown options. Ideally, the dropdown would only appear and be selectable on PayPal's page after the user has been redirected to it.

```
<div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:...buynow.jpg)" 
     href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('registerFrm').submit();">
    <form id="registerFrm" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="TG5...">
        <table>
            <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Pick A DAY">Pick A DAY</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
            <option value="1">Day 1 $10.00 USD</option>
            <option value="2">Day 2 $10.00 USD</option>
            </select> </td></tr>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    </form>
</div>
```

I am not sure if maybe I need to somehow delay submitting the form to PayPal, or even potentially split my two options up into two different images (which I'd really like to avoid) and submit the form based on which image/option the user clicks.

After a few hours of searching SO and the PayPal documentation I couldn't find anything that seemed like this, so I am probably using the wrong terminology. Any help or examples of something similar would be helpful.

Comment: As far as I know, all customization for an order must be done on your site before your redirect to the PayPal checkout page. I do not think you can put your dropdown-list (*the `select`*) on PayPal's page. I could be mistaken, though. If you simply do not like the way it looks, though, you could hide your form completely (including the `select` element), show the two options, and then when a user selects one of the two options, you could use javascript to change value of the hidden `select` element. That's probably not what you are looking for, but it's just a thought.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quick. I think that I will probably end up doing what you said. Hide everything, show my two options (maybe in a modal) and then submit the form based on whatever the user clicks.